# how can I print "\' in c++?

Tags: c++, cout

I have a homework assignment where part of the menu has to have `"R\C"` printed, but when I run the program the console just prints `"RC"`. Does anyone know why is this happening and how I can fix it?

This is what I have in Visual Studio:

```
cout << "R\C" << endl;
```

Answer (score 5):

The `\C` is being interpreted as an (invalid) [escape sequence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape).  You need to escape the `\` character as `\\` in order to print it as a single `\`, eg:

```
cout << "R\\C" << endl;
```

Alternatively, in C++11 and later, you can use a [*raw* string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) instead, so you do not need to escape the `\` character:

```
cout << R"(R\C)" << endl;
```

Answer (score 3):

Escape `\` with another `\`:

```
cout << "R\\C" << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

c++ reserve some characters, so you can't directly input them, usually you will have to put \ in front of them to signify that you want to use "\" as a string.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use escape sequences for certain characters.  For the character that you specified you would have to output as `“\\”` and your output would be `\`.  Other escape sequences are:

- `\’`
- `\t` For Tab
- `\n` For newline
- `\?` For question marks

See [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use escape sequences.., like **\t**, **\n**, **\a**...

If you want to print ' \ ', you have to code like this

```
cout<<"\\";
```